# How to add an image at end of video in android using MediaApis?

Tags: android, media, video-editing, mediamuxer, mediaextractor

I have a link to a .mp4 video and I would like my app to share it. However instead of sharing the link, I would like to extract 10 sec of the video and  attach the sharer's profile name and picture at the end of the video for 1 sec like TikTok does.

I have managed to extract the required duration of video using MediaExtractor but i am not able to figure out how I would be able to attach an image and text at end for few frames.